# How to call sp with named parameters without any order in laravel

Tags: sql-server, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have one sp for inserting the data, it has three params, Ex: a,b,c. so I want to run the sp with params, but not able to find the solution in laravel.

This is what i tried.

```
DB::select('EXEC sp_name @a=a, @b=b, @c=c');
```

But, its not working.

Comment: why select and not `DB::raw`

Comment: Post your complete query :)

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer. only quote was missing

This is the working example

```
DB::select("EXEC sp_name @a='a', @b='b', @c='c'");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$a=1;
$b=2;
$c=3;
$data=DB::select('call sp_name(?,?,?)',[$a,$b,$c]);
```

Comment: Please read my question, i have asked about named parameters, in your answer. i have to keep the order, which i don't want

Comment: Sorry, But you have not mentioned anything about the order of the parameters. You just asked how to call sp with parameters this is what exactly you asked  "I want to run the sp with params". If you don't ask question clearly you won't see right answer!